# How do I get the name of the current task in Capistrano 3?

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

In Capistrano 2.x I could use `current_task.name` inside a task to get the current task's name. Is there something similar in Capistrano 3?

Comment: If you just want to see the task name in the log, try [airbrussh](https://github.com/mattbrictson/airbrussh) (cap 3 only)

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out:

```
task :foo do |task|
  current_task_name = task.name_with_args
end
```